# Flutterweb gorouter path with parameters show blank screen

Tags: flutter, gorouter

I am using gorouter in flutter to navigate. whenever i use context.push("/article/1234") it goes to proper page but if I put the link directly in browser I get a blank screen.

following is my code

```
GoRoute(
      path: "/article/:id",
      builder:(context,state) =>  ArticleScreen(id:state.params['id']),
    ),
```

if i use below code it works as expected but if i put the url in browser it shows a blank page

```
context.go("/article/1234");
```

Comment: happening same on my project. let me know if you find any fix for this

Comment: Did you have a look to the network request / response? There's probably an HTTP error no?

Comment: Please can you provide some context: i.e. Flutter web version, and go_router version, and the URL that you put in the browser when it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This issue is fixed and merged in the Flutter's master channel. Might get live in the future stable releases.

GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/120430) to keep track of the problem.

Also, I could not find permanent fix for this but I found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/118684) pull request which actually gives a fix the problem.

You can also configure the `main.dart.js` and `flutter_service_worker.js` URLs in the `index.html` file as described in this comment to something that matches your app:

```
  _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
    entrypointUrl: "/YOUR_APP_BASE/main.dart.js",
    serviceWorker: {
      serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
      serviceWorkerUrl: "/YOUR_APP_BASE/flutter_service_worker.js?v=",
    },
```

That way the files will be requested from their "absolute" URL, rather than URLs relative to the ones specified by the PathStrategy.

(If your base URL is "/", you just need: `/main.dart.js` and `/flutter_service_worker.js?v=`)